# Socket queue (Twitter streaming as a reference)

Tags: python, sockets, twitter, streaming, low-level

I just found out Twitter streaming endpoints support detection of slow connections somehow.

Reference: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#stall_warnings (and bottom of page)

Idea is that socket send will probably process data one by one. And it knows when one packet is received by client so it can maintain queue and always know of it's size.

It's easy when client sends some confirmation packets for each of them. But that is not the case with Twitter Streaming API - it's a one-way transfer.

My question is: how did they achieve that? I can't see a way to do it without some very low level raw socket support - but I may be forgetting something here. With some low level support we could probably get ACKs for each packets. Is that even possible? Can ACKs be somehow traced?

Any other ideas how this was done?
Any way to do this e.g. in Python? Or any other language example would be appreciated.

Or maybe I am over my head here and it simply uses to track how many bytes are not yet processed through socket.send? But isn't it a poor indication of client's connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started off thinking along the same lines as you but I think the implementation is actually much easier than we both expect.

Twitter's API docs state:-

*"A client reads data too slowly. Every streaming connection is backed by a queue of messages to be sent to the client. If this queue grows too large over time, the connection will be closed."* - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/connecting#Disconnections

Based on the above I imagine Twitter will have a thread that is pushing tweets onto a queue and a long lived http connection to a client (kept open with a while loop) that pops a message off the queue and writes the data to the http response during each loop iteration.

Now if you imagine what happens inside the while loop and you think in terms of buffers, Twitter will pop an item off the queue then write the tweet data to some kind of output buffer, that buffer will get flushed and then fill up a TCP buffer for transport to the client.

If a client is reading data slowly from its TCP buffer then the **server's** TCP send buffer will fill up meaning that when the server's output buffer is flushed it will **block** because the data cannot be written to the TCP buffer which consequently means that the while loop is not popping tweets off the queue as often (because it is being blocked when data is being flushed) causing the tweet queue to fill up.

Now you would just need a check at the beginning of each loop iteration to check whether the Tweet queue has reached some predefined threshold.

Comment: That was what I ended up with as well. Thanks for great answer!